# is it possible to run asp.net application in the context of an account of differnt domain

Tags: iis, authentication, active-directory, trust

Suppose i work in a company ABC.com and another parent company domain XYZ.com. What must I do to run the ASP.net application hosted in a machine at ABC.com but use the windows credentials of XYZ.com?

Thanks in advance

---

Is it necessary to establish a trust level between the domains? Currently the following errors are shown when I try to impersonate the user of another domain

*Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.*

Also should there be one way or two trust between the domains. Will it suffice to establish a trust on the domain XYZ.com in ABC.com?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [ProcessModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1(v=vs.100).aspx) section in the ASP.net config.

Comment: link needs to be updated or copy-paste some of the text onto here?